# Export matplotlib basemap to SVG

Tags: python, svg, matplotlib-basemap

How can I save a basemap created by the code below in Python as a SVG image (a *.pdf file would also do the job as it can easily be converted)?

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# lon_0 is central longitude of projection.
# resolution = 'c' means use crude resolution coastlines.
m = Basemap(projection='robin',lon_0=0,resolution='c')
m.drawcoastlines()
m.fillcontinents(color='coral',lake_color='aqua')
# draw parallels and meridians.
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90.,120.,30.))
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(0.,360.,60.))
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')
plt.title("Robinson Projection")
plt.show()
```

[image: to SVG]

Source: *https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/robin.html*

Applying `plt.savefig("filename.pdf")` only yields a white/emtpy file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason that `plt.savefig(filename)` wouldn't work?

By specifying the file format in the filename, you can make it any format you want. For example, if you want a .pdf you would type `plt.savefig("filename.pdf")`.

Comment: Sorry no, this yields an empty/white PDF/SVG :(

Comment: Try it before `plt.show()`, I think depending on your backend `plt.show()` might clear the figure.